# How to delete form fill autocomplete / autocorrection suggestions from Safari

Tags: safari, settings, web-browser, auto-complete

How to delete these kinds of auto-fill suggestions from Safari?!

[image]

I have cleared all in the AutoFill options, but these previously mistyped entries remain?!

Comment: I think that's [auto-correct](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/check-spelling-and-grammar-on-mac-mchlp2299/mac), not auto-fill.

Comment: But why on earth would a mistyped form field value end up in the autocorrection dictionary?!

Comment: [Tsetse is a word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsetse_(disambiguation)), as in [Tsetse Fly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsetse_fly). It's a word in Apple's dictionary, which you can easily test by typing "testme" in any native text field: "tsetse" is suggested as the closest word in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the [same problem in Freeform](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/460771/89110) but it turns out this is a common behavior that can be observed in Safari and other Apple apps. Just go to

**Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Correct Spelling Automatically**

And uncheck "Correct Spelling Automatically".