# How to disable autocorrection in Freeform?

Tags: settings, text, auto-complete, autocorrect, freeform

I'm really annoyed with automatic capitalization in Freeform, for example here I tried to type "yes" 4 times before I finally got "Yes":
[image: Free form]
Clicking that cross with mouse require you to move hand from keyboard which takes valuable seconds while editing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that we can disable autocorrect (and auto-capitalize) behavior in any Apple app (Freeform, Safari, TextEdit, ...) in the Edit menu:

**Edit > Spelling and Grammar > Correct Spelling Automatically**

Make sure that is unchecked.

[image: Disabling spelling auto-correct in Freeform]